# Error occurring in arbitrary frequency during Capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, minitest

In an App I write I create, update and delete Objects of a 'places' class. Depending on whether a user is logged in or not the place needs to be reviewed first before it becomes visible to the public inside an index view.

We use Minitest and Capybara as our testing framework from the beginning on we had trouble with some of our Capybara specs...

a) ... passing and not passing on different machines (especially on our local systems and Travis CI)

b) ... passing and not passing seemingly arbitrary throughout different runs on our local machines

I have to admit it's a bit of a miracle for me and even harder to track down the sources of errors. The following specs show this behaviour:

```
require_relative '../../test_helper'

feature 'Review place' do
  before do
    create(:place, :reviewed)
  end

  scenario 'Do not show user edits in review index', :js do
    login
    visit '/places/1/edit'
    fill_in('place_name', with: 'USER CHANGE')
    click_on('Update Place')
    visit '/places/review_index'
    page.wont_have_content('USER CHANGE')
  end

  scenario 'Show guest edits in review index and review place', :js do
    visit '/places/1/edit'
    fill_in('place_name', with: 'GUEST CHANGE')
    validate_captcha
    click_on('Update Place')
    login
    visit '/places/review_index'
    page.must_have_content('SomeReviewedPlace')
    visit '/1/review_place'
    sleep(1)
    page.must_have_content('SomeReviewedPlace')
    page.must_have_content('GUEST CHANGE')
  end
end
```

and

```
require_relative '../../test_helper'

feature 'Edit place' do
  before do
    create(:place, :reviewed)
  end

  scenario 'Do valid place update as user and show in index afterwards', :js do
    login
    visit '/places/1/edit'

    fill_in('place_name', with: 'Any place')
    fill_in('place_street', with: 'Schulze-Boysen-Str.')
    fill_in('place_house_number', with: '80')
    fill_in('place_postal_code', with: '10963')
    fill_in('place_city', with: 'Berlin')
    fill_in('place_email', with: 'schnipp@schnapp.com')
    fill_in('place_homepage', with: 'http://schnapp.com')
    fill_in('place_phone', with: '03081763253')
    click_on('Update Place')
    visit '/places'

    page.must_have_content('Any place')
    page.must_have_content('10963 Berlin')
  end

  scenario 'Do valid place update as guest and show in index afterwards as to be reviewed', :js do
    visit '/places/1/edit'
    fill_in('place_name', with: 'Some changes')
    validate_captcha
    click_on('Update Place')
    visit '/places'

    page.must_have_content('Some changes')
    page.must_have_css('.glyphicon-eye-open')
  end

  scenario 'Do valid place update as guest and do not show changes within other users session', :js do
    visit '/places/1/edit'
    fill_in('place_name', with: 'SomeOtherName')
    validate_captcha
    click_on('Update Place')

    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    visit '/places'
    page.wont_have_content('SomeOtherName')
    page.must_have_content('SomeReviewedPlace')
    page.wont_have_css('.glyphicon-eye-open')
  end
end
```

Both tests arbitrarily fail with

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Place with 'id'=1

although such a place has to exist due to

```
before do
  create(:place, :reviewed)
end
```

Running the test files individually the error does not appear, only SOMETIMES within the complete chain that's passed within `rake test`. Does anyone have a clue why?

best and thanks,
Andi

Comment: Here's something to try: next time it fails, note the seed that the tests ran with and then rerun the tests, passing in `--option rand:<thatseed>` and see if it fails again. Also, what javascript driver are you using? EDIT: re-running with the same seed guarantees that the run order of the tests is the same as the failed run. if you can reproduce it consistently with the same seed you might have some instability based upon what tests ran before it.

Comment: you can identify the javascript driver by putting `puts page.driver.class` in one of your tests.

Comment: Hey, adding `--option rand:<thatseed>``does not work (`invalid option: --option`

Comment: @jaydel: got it, `rake test TESTOPTS="--seed=1261` works for me, thanks for the hint, really helped me finding the bug!

Comment: cool. on a side note, `--option` is a brain fart. It should be `--order` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your tests

The first is that the before block is run before each scenario, and when the second scenario is run the id of the object created is probably 2 (unless the previous scenario created more places then it would be higher), etc.  To solve this you should be saving the object you're creating and then using its id to generate the path to visit

```
before do
  @place = create(:place, :reviewed)
end
```

then when you need to visit it

```
visit("/places/#{@place.id}/edit")
```

or using the route helpers

```
visit(edit_place_path(@place))  # preferred unless you're actually testing the text used for the url
```

The second issue is that you're not waiting for click_on to complete whatever it's doing before visiting a new location.  When using JS capable drivers there is no guarantee that actions triggered by browser clicks/interactions have completed when those actions return.  You need to check for visible changes that indicate the actions are complete before visiting a new location or the new visit can cancel the action triggered or get processed before it completes.

```
click_on('Update Place')
page.must_have_content('Place Updated') #whatever message is displayed
visit '/places'
```

Comment: Thanks, both hints seem plausible to me. Unfortunately they do not solve the problem... Is it correct that none of the commits within the feature tests gets stored permanently to the DB? In other words: Is the test DB being reset before a new scenario gets tested?

Comment: @A.Neumann When doing non-js tests that would be correct. However for JS tests they have to be committed - and then use something like database_cleaner between scenarios to truncate or delete the created records.  This is needed because in JS tests the app runs in a separate thread, with a separate database connection, so if the records aren't actually committed it would never see them.  I did not suggest that because you said sometimes the tests pass which should not be the case.

Comment: Mmmhh... I thought so too. But debugging the whole files containing the specs above reveals, that the changes appearing at the end of the spec (they are there!) do not get committed and hence are not visible within other tests (which is something I actually want)!? I don't have database cleaner installed...

Comment: It works now, I had a minor bug. The last question remains, though. Thanks for your help. your hint was very useful!